# Loop until future values are higher than previous fixed value (max nrow)

Tags: r

Ok here goes. Right now the code is set to on `signal == 1`, store the comparison price. It stores the comparison price on the same line has `signal == 1`.

The goal is to on `signal == 1`. Store the next comparison price +`1 row below signal == 1`.

```
new.df <- data.frame(new.df,response=0)
    input <- new.df$close.detrend.n11 # Input column for code
    signal <- new.df$detrend.signal.n11
    nlines <- 10 # Time Stop

state <- "off"
for (i in 1:nrow(new.df)) { # loop through data
  if (state == "off") { # off state, loop does nothing until signal = 1
    if (signal[i] == 0) {
      next
    } else { # signal = 1 encountered, if not a 0 it will do whats below...
      comparison_price <- input[i] # save current price for comparing ### Set to +1 row below signal ==1 row)
      n_comparisons <- 0              # keep track of how many comparisons 
      state <- "on"                   # change state to "on"
    }
  } else if (state == "on") { # Above turned on as found signal = 1
    new.df$response[i] <- 1 
    if (input[i] > comparison_price & n_comparisons >= 1) { # found higher price and line travel >=1, travel after +1 line to find nearest future highest price
      state <- "off" # Turns off as found higher price, now does nothing until signal == 1
    } else if (n_comparisons == 10) { # If no higher price and comparisons >=1, turn off
      state <- "off"  # Turns off as max limit reached
      n_comparisons <- 0   # Sets count to 0
      if (signal[i] == 1) {  # Find signal match
        comparison_price <- input[i] # Set price for comparing  ### Set to +1 row below signal ==1 row)
        n_comparisons <- 0 # Sets count to 0
        state <- "off"    # Turn off 
      }
    } else if (n_comparisons == nlines) { # hit comparison limit
      state <- "off"  # Turns off as max limit reached
      n_comparisons <- 0   # Sets count to 0
      if (signal[i] == 1) { # Finds signal ==1
        comparison_price <- input[i] # Set price for comparing ### Set to +1 row below signal ==1 row)
        n_comparisons <- 0 # Set count to 0
        state <- "on" # Turn On
      }
    } else { # price less or equal to comparison price
      n_comparisons <- n_comparisons + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Dummy data below:

`new.df` below:

```
  detrend.signal.n11 response close.detrend.n11
1                   0        0       0.002044539
2                   0        0      -0.022593487
3                   1        0      -0.031842265
4                   1        1      -0.065392575
5                   0        1      -0.043699817
6                   0        1      -0.014110718
7                   0        0      -0.021899531
8                   0        0      -0.013908376
9                   0        0      -0.019580252
10                  0        0       0.023034983
11                  0        0       0.014598769
12                  0        0       0.013928860
13                  0        0       0.008568669
14                  0        0       0.020220697
15                  0        0      -0.003770356
16                  0        0      -0.021588957
17                  0        0      -0.018637185
18                  0        0      -0.007193684
19                  0        0      -0.013691624
20                  0        0      -0.020903833
21                  1        0      -0.036922613
22                  0        1      -0.011845136
23                  0        1       0.001115208
24                  0        0       0.018121000
25                  0        0       0.027648296
26                  0        0       0.016920882
27                  0        0       0.006321574
28                  0        0      -0.012052026
29                  0        0      -0.017340348
30                  0        0      -0.029062592
31                  0        0      -0.012560974
32                  0        0      -0.029126952
33                  0        0      -0.026220867
34                  0        0       0.007337385
35                  0        0       0.009356641
36                  0        0       0.027851405
37                  0        0       0.044130597
38                  0        0       0.036630768
39                  0        0       0.028685373
40                  0        0       0.030813270
41                  0        0       0.020690203
42                  0        0       0.014865516
43                  0        0      -0.001644471
44                  0        0       0.011208823
45                  0        0       0.009698927
```

Comment: What is the procedure if you hit the next `signal = 1` before you manage to find a higher closing price?

Comment: you just reminded me that I wanted to print +1 until a future higher close. After the higher close condition was met within 10 row span, then it would print 0 until next 'signal =1' edited post to reflect this

Comment: each time we meet signal=1 we start the loop again, even its very close to the previous signal = 1

Comment: Going to edit the code you wrote to cater to if we hit a signal == 1 when we have not found a higher closing price, it is to turn off.... will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Line 26 turned off seems to do the trick. I step by step on paper wrote the logic of your code. Line by line. It pinged when i found the correct one that needed to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a skeleton of a solution

```
prices <- round(cumsum(c(1400, rnorm(99, 20, 40))), 2)
signal <- sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
df <- data.frame(
    price = prices,
    signal = signal,
    response = 0
)

state <- "off"
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { # loop through data
    if (state == "off") { # off state, loop does nothing until signal = 1
        if (df$signal[i] == 0) {
            next
        } else { # signal = 1 encountered
            comparison_price <- df$price[i] # save current price for comparing
            n_comparisons <- 0              # keep track of how many comparisons
            state <- "on"                   # change state to "on"
        }
    } else if (state == "on") {
        df$response[i] <- 1
        if (df$price[i] > comparison_price) { # found higher price
            state <- "off"
            if (df$signal[i] == 1) {
                comparison_price <- df$price[i]
                n_comparisons <- 0
                state <- "on"
            }
        } else if (n_comparisons == 10) { # hit comparison limit
            state <- "off"
            n_comparisons <- 0
            if (df$signal[i] == 1) {
                comparison_price <- df$price[i]
                n_comparisons <- 0
                state <- "on"
            }
        } else { # price less or equal to comparison price
            n_comparisons <- n_comparisons + 1
        }
    }
}

df
```

The key is to maintain some kind of state as you traverse your data, here I've used a simple `"on"/"off"` state. The search for the a future higher value only turns `"on"` after hitting a 1 signal. It also turns itself off after 10 failed comparisons. As is it does not handle the case where it finds a higher value on the same row as a 1 signal, it will shut itself off on such a row but you can add code to turn it back on.

EDIT:

The index `i` denotes your row number in this code, the `for` loop goes through values `1, 2, ..., n` for your `n` rows of data. So if you want the next row you use `i + 1`.

```
if (signal[i] == 1) {  # Find signal match
        comparison_price <- input[i + 1] # Set price for comparing  ### Set to +1 row below signal ==1 row)
        n_comparisons <- 0 # Sets count to 0
        state <- "off"    # Turn off 
}
```

However if you discover a `signal == 1` on the final row of your data then there is no next row, so you will need to figure out how to handle that.

Comment: Can this print a +1 until it finds a future higher close value? Once it meets a future higher close value it would print 0 until it finds next signal = 1. Then it would print +1 until a future higher close value, on higher close, after it would begin to print 0 again, so and and so forth!

Comment: It can, do you understand wha the code is doing? You should be able to edit this example to suit your exact needs.

Comment: Great it is almost there, when I run a test it prints a +1 at the high, however, it is not printinga +1 when price is equal to or less than comparison price, i edited a sample output to my post.

Comment: I'm put in the changes you needed. It was a single line change and you should try to learn what's going on so you can make these changes yourself.

Comment: I have never seen code quite like this. New learning for me - thank you

Comment: I also generally understand what is happening. Only confusion I have is the # price less or equal to comparison price line. I keep tracking to wanting to see a <= sign versus it being in an else context, cant make the connection on my end with it. The n_comparisons variable also is stated as 0. Not making the connection here on my end

Comment: Shian: I wanted to add a condition that if price > comparison after 1 day, ignore, and continue to the loop for the highest price within 10max. I tried to edit line 18 to if (input[i] > comparison_price & n_comparisons >= 1) thinking after n_comparison line is over 1 and we loop until a higher price... we exit... however, it seems that both conditions would be met when there is a higher price first... and that we travel over 1 line. the net result is a travel of 2 lines and off. So looks like I need to add another few lines here. Still working on the problem.

Comment: if (input[i] > comparison_price & n_comparisons >= 1)  stay on... and loop until (input[i] > comparison_price)... seems that should work...

Comment: Shian: Which part of the code places a +1 in the next line down from a signal == 1. there is a +1 lag in the code.

Comment: `df$response[i] <- 1` is what sets the response. I can't really tell what you're trying to do now. But to understand the code you need to keep track of `i`, `state` and  `n_comparisons` as you move through the code.

Comment: K i think I'm getting a handle on it. I edited it to ignore repeat signal == 1. And it made it too, that if the next day after entering the loop was higher, ignore and loop until the next higher price. So 2x good changes. The one im trying to do now is to on signal == 1. Place the comparison price on the next line instead.

Comment: ' } else { # signal = 1 encountered, if not a 0 it will do whats below...
      comparison_price <- input[i] # save current price for comparing
      n_comparisons <- 0              # keep track of how many comparisons
      state <- "on"                   # change state to "on"', Right now if signal ==1, it sets comparrison price, how would I make it set the price on +1 line below signal ==1?

Comment: I think it's better if you just edit your original question with your code and exactly what you're doing to do now as it's quite hard to read things in comments.

Comment: k check it out now. I did make some edits to the original... as you will see

Comment: I've edited my solution. In the future just add to your original question instead of replacing it, that way other people can actually figure out what's going on. Also it sounds like like you're not familiar with for loops and you should probably go through an introductory R programming tutorial before working on this any further.